# Rancher Dashboard, ETCD has no Grafana

Tags: kubernetes

I have a rancher dashboard and I have a Kubernetes cluster (the cluster is configured by "rke up" command). I have imported the cluster into rancher dashboard and then enable the monitoring. At final all components has grafana enabled except ETCD.
How can I enable it?
I'm a new user to kubernetes and rancher.
Regards

[ETCD-NO GRAFANA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4Me6.png)

Comment: I should mention that "controller manager" and "scheduler" has garafana icon but the graph "kubernetes componets" has no data

Comment: when I add nodes into rancher dashboard by "importing nodes" instead of "importing cluster" everything is fine.